# MySQL - Ignore insert to mapping when duplicate entry by two unique columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mapping table for movie and actor. My query to insert data looks like: `"INSERT IGNORE INTO movie_actor_mapping (actor_id, movie_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"`. And here I have to ignore duplicate rows, for example I have to ignore data like this: `1 | 21 | 1` if this data is exist. But don't know how to modify my query or table do that because here two columns that must be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_actor_mapping` (
  `movie_actor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_actor_id`),
)
```

Data in this table looks like this: `1 | 21 | 1`

Comment: 1) Why did you have a movie_actor_id and not the other 2 as primary keys? 2) Do you want to skip the insert if the values (movie_id, actor_id) are already in the table?

Comment: Hi! 1) hard to say because I am novice in databases and I not sure that I do it correct. 2 ) yes, I have to skip insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an m:m relationship you normally have both the keys from the entities in your cross table: So in your example your table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_actor_mapping` (
    `movie_id` int(10) unsigned,
    `actor_id` int(10) unsigned,
     PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
)
```

Now if you insert a new entry with already existing entries you will get an SQL Error Saying, that you cant have duplicate entries for your primary keys, as Primary Keys are by default also unique

Comment: Thank you so much!